# How do I find the file containing all the values for a hidden tag if i know its name?

Tags: html, forms

Given these three inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" name="codes" value="MTY1fHw5fDE=">
<input type="hidden" name="id_codes" value="165">
<input type="hidden" name="shiny" value="1">
```

How would I find a list of all the values for the first tag using a value of the second and third.

The value of the first tag is directly connected to the value of the second tag and the value of the third tag.

The value of the third tag is from 1 to 5 and the value of the second tag is from 1-721.

If I know the values of the second and third tags, is there some way for me to get the value of the first tag? This is html.

Comment: what on earth are you asking?

Comment: I am trying to find the value of "codes" using a specific value of 'id_codes" and "shiny"

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).